# Downloaded Ubuntu ISO always has wrong checksum?

Tags: iso

I have a problem when i try to download the maverick iso. after download i always get the wrong iso checksum with gtkhash? I already tried from several locations provided via the ubuntu page but not succeeded.

The hash should be

```
59d15a16ce90c8ee97fa7c211b7673a8 ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso
```

i get

```
681689736dcdf7dc28384836eed6e55f
```

or

```
9174d1e4767d2c3e5b365444d0c8a771
```

**Update: Downloading the image via torrent seems more reliable than via http or ftp because of the internal torrent checksum tests**

Comment: Can you append both the source-hash and the one you're getting to your question?

Comment: yes, just updated my question.

Comment: That sounds like a typical hardware (memory or disk) issue or a filesystem bug.

Comment: Have you tried booting the disk and selecting "Check Disk for Errors" from the boot-menu? (hit return while the little icon appears, right at the beginning of the boot process)

Comment: @Stefano: No i haven't even burned the iso. I tried the torrent solution without checking the iso after downloading and burned it now and the image worked.

Comment: @JanC i assume meanwhile that it's a problem with my router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest downloading from a different source and then checking the md5. I have good results from linuxtracker.org for both speed and reliability with checksums.

Comment: just torrents there?